# How to get pdf Files in android targeting android 11 using MediaStore?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Here in the below code, I try to get pdf files from the whole device in android 10 and 11 but I did not get my code is going right until the cursor when I put the condition on cursor cannot be null. (if(cursor!=null) { while (cursor moveToFirst) {}})but in while condition my cursor not going I do not know?

```
 protected fun getPdfList(): ArrayList<String>? {
    val pdfList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()     
valprojection=arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
            MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE)
    val sortOrder: String = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"
    val selection: String = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + " =?"valmimeType:String=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(mimeType)
    valcollection:Uri=if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
    }
    contentResolver.query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder).use { cursor -> 
        val idColumn= cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)
        val nameColumn=cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
        if(cursor!=null) {
            while (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val id = cursor.getLong(idColumn)
                val name = cursor.getString(nameColumn)
            }
        }
    }
    return pdfList
}
```

Comment: please anyone can help me I'v stuck about a week

Comment: cursor.getCount()?

Comment: Remove .DATA from projection.